# Analyze frames colors displayed in AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer. Image Buffer is nil

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-toolbox

I want to analyze colors displayed in `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` which gets frames from the data source which I don't control.

I've made my own subclass of this class and override `func enqueue(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer)` to get my hands on sample buffers. My plan was to create CIImage from it and then apply `CIAreaAverage` filter.

Unfortunately, when I call `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)`, I get `null`. 
From what I understand, this means that I should use `dataBuffer` instead. But how can I convert it into CIImage?

Comment: What is `dataBuffer`? How you get `sampleBuffer`? From `AVCaptureSession`?

Comment: `dataBuffer` is a variable on `CMSampleBuffer`. I get those samples from the 3rd party library, and they are getting those frames from the network (these frames don't come from a device camera).